# Error while installing hubot on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, hubot

When I run `yo hubot` the following error comes up

```
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "hubot"
"hubot-scripts" "hubot-diagnostics" "hubot-help" "hubot-heroku-keepalive" "hubot-google-images"
"hubot-google-translate" "hubot-pugme" "hubot-maps" "hubot-redis-brain"
 "hubot-rules" "hubot-shipit" "--save"
```

Why is this happening? I have tried running `sudo npm install hubot-rules` but it doesn't seem to work. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that you need to own the `~/.npm` directory. You can run this command to do so:

`$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) "$HOME/.npm"`